# Salesforce Date/Time value with optional Time portion

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

In my Salesforce application I want to user to enter **Date/Time** value, but time portion is optional. Is there any way to accomplish this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If the time is optional just use 00 for that:

```
Datetime myDate = datetime.newInstance(2012, 10, 5, 00, 00, 0);
```

Comment: Hi mast0r! Thanks a lot for your idea. But once we defined DateTime field with Custom Object, we must set the time potion on Visual Force page level, other wise it will produce validation error. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Can you not use two fields (one date and another text field for time).  Then concatenation of these fields into a date time formula field.  Will this not help?

Comment: Hi user1420829! So sorry your answer is not clear enough for me, can you please explain further. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As a solution, rather than using custom object filed type DateTime value, I have keep separate Date value and Time value in VF controller level and with the compose those values make a DateTime.

Apex code is as bellow,

```
 // Compos DateTime with Date & Time values 
    this.jobOccurrence.Date_Time_Sampled__c = DateTime.parse(this.dateSampled.trim() + ' ' + this.timeSampled.trim());
```

VisualForce code is as bellow,

```
<apex:page>

   <!-- Style sheet for timepicker -->
   <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" type="text/css" href="{!URLFOR($Resource.jquery_ui_custom)}" />

   <style>
       #ui-datepicker-div, .ui-datepicker{ font-size: 70%; }     
      .ui-timepicker-div .ui-widget-header { margin-bottom: 8px; }
      .ui-timepicker-div dl { text-align: left; }
      .ui-timepicker-div dl dt { height: 25px; margin-bottom: -25px; }
      .ui-timepicker-div dl dd { margin: 0 10px 10px 65px; }
      .ui-timepicker-div td { font-size: 90%; }
      .ui-tpicker-grid-label { background: none; border: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; 

   </style>


   <!-- javascript for timepicker -->
   <script type="text/javascript" src="{!URLFOR($Resource.jquery)}"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="{!URLFOR($Resource.jquery_ui_custom_min)}"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="{!URLFOR($Resource.jquery_ui_timepicker_addon)}"></script>

   <script type="text/javascript">  

     /* Set Timepicker to component */    
     function setTimepicker(componentObj) {      
      $(componentObj).timepicker({ show24Hours: false, timeFormat: 'hh:mm TT', ampm: true});          
     }
   </script> 

 <apex:form id="frmMain">

   <!-- Date -->                       
   <apex:inputText value="{!dateSampled}" onfocus="DatePicker.pickDate(false, this.id, false);"/>
   <!-- Time --> 
   <apex:inputText value="{!timeSampled}" onfocus="setTimepicker(this);"/> 

 </apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

Comment: This solution only works as long as timezones are not involved and you just assume to use the correct one. Wanted to point that out as it might be important for some folks.